# Where can I find the exact command nautilus uses to mount a network share

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus

#### Problem

I am looking to see if there is a way to find the exact command nautilus uses to mount network shares.

#### Background

I find that the specific way that nautilus mounts network shares is better than my current way of using the command line and I want to find out why that is the case.

[image]

I'm able to mount the network share using the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=3.1.1,rw,noperm,username=gfair,password='********',iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,soft,user //10.42.0.43/g /home/gfair/stargate/g
```

#### System

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver.
`4.18.0-24-generic #25~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 20 11:13:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Considering it depends on it, it's probably using [gvfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVfs)

Comment: Interestingly, when I try to use `gvfs-mount` it says that its been deprecated and to use `gio mount` instead